# AWS EC2: HTTPS access error – browsers don’t see the certificate used for configuring SSL in Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, ssl-certificate

I configured SSL offload on Elastic Load Balancer using a certificate from AWS Certificate Manager.

The HTTPS listener is configured as follows: the default action is forwarding to Group Instances HTTPS, and the default SSL certificate is (as Edit Listener indicates) the correct one issued by ACM for a domain name I registered using AWS.

In Route 53 Hosted Zones, I created an A-type record with my Public IPv4 address (which is an Elastic IP) as a value.

However, when I try to connect to my domain via https, I get the error message ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID, and Chrome’s Developer tools > Security > View Certificate displays

```
  Issued to:    ip-172-31-90-31.ec2.internal

  Issued by:    ip-172-31-90-31.ec2.internal,
```

that is my Private IPv4 DNS in both cases -- instead of my domain name (for Issued to) and Amazon (for Issued by).

I also tried pointing the A record to the ALB instead of my public IPv4 (as suggested at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html). Unfortunately, after that browsers couldn't connect to the domain at all (the error message: <domain_name> took too long to respond).

I am wondering what could cause that. Could it result from some misconfiguration of my Apache server? If so, how could I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure SSL offload at ALB, you should point your A record to the ALB instead of your IPv4.

Please follow this guide and check if it works: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I did what you suggested: chose
 

Alias to Application and Classic Load Balancer;
 

my EC2 instance's region as Region;
 

dualstack.SquareTestRoute53-119498759.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com as the balancer name (suggested by default).
 

Unfortunately, after now browsers can't connect to the server at all: the error message is <domain_name> took too long to respond.
  

I would greatly appreciate your advice on this.

Comment: Did you config the target group correctly? Anh can you check Security Groups of EC2 if it allows traffic from ALB or not?

Comment: Thank you so much for your recommendations, Ash Blake – they really helped. I edited the ACL, and now I can connect to my instance using both https and http. Unfortunately, another problem sprung up (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71461545/ec2-instance-can-t-access-the-internet). If you could advise me on it, I would be enormously grateful.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get a valid public SSL certificate for `ip-172-31-90-31.ec2.internal`. This is not your domain, but it belongs to AWS. You have to obtained/buy your own domain, e.g. `myapp.org` for which you can get a free SSL certificate from AWS ACM.