# EC2 instance can’t access the internet

Tags: amazon-ec2, tcp, firewall, ping, acl

Apparently, my EC2 instance can’t access the internet properly. Here is what happens when I try to install a Python module:
`[ec2-user@ip-172-31-90-31 ~]$ pip3 install flask`
`Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable`
`WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fab198cbe10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/flask/`
etc.

However, the website that is hosted on the same EC2 instance can be accessed using both http and https.

The security group is configured as follows:

| Port range | Protocol | Source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 80 | TCP | 0.0.0.0/0 |
| 22 | TCP | 0.0.0.0/0 |
| 80 | TCP | ::/0 |
| 22 | TCP | ::/0 |
| 443 | TCP | 0.0.0.0/0 |
| 443 | TCP | ::/0 |

The ACL inbound rules are:

| Type | Protocol | Port range | Source | Allow/Deny |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HTTP (80) | TCP (6) | 80 | 0.0.0.0/0 | Allow |
| SSH (22) | TCP (6) | 22 | 0.0.0.0/0 | Allow |
| HTTPS (443) | TCP (6) | 443 | 0.0.0.0/0 | Allow |
| All ICMP - IPv4 | ICMP (1) | All | 0.0.0.0/0 | Allow |
| All trafic | All | All | 0.0.0.0/0 | Deny |

and the outbound rules are:

| Type | Protocol | Port range | Source | Allow/Deny |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Custom TCP | TCP (6) | 1024 - 65535 | 0.0.0.0/0 | Allow |
| HTTP (80) | TCP (6) | 80 | 0.0.0.0/0 | Allow |
| SSH (22) | TCP (6) | 22 | 0.0.0.0/0 | Allow |
| HTTPS (443) | TCP (6) | 443 | 0.0.0.0/0 | Allow |
| All ICMP - IPv4 | ICMP (1) | All | 0.0.0.0/0 | Allow |
| All trafic | All | All | 0.0.0.0/0 | Deny |

This is what the route table associated with the subnet looks like:

| Destination | Target | Status | Propagated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 172.31.0.0/16 | local | Active | No |
| 0.0.0.0/0 | igw-09b554e4da387238c | Active | No |

(no explicit or edge associations).

As for the firewall, executing `sudo iptables –L`  results in

`Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)`
`target     prot opt source               destination`

`Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)`
`target     prot opt source               destination`

`Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)`
`target     prot opt source               destination`

and `sudo iptables -L -t nat` gives

`Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)`
`target     prot opt source               destination`

`Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)`
`target     prot opt source               destination`

`Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)`
`target     prot opt source               destination`

`Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)`
`target     prot opt source               destination`

What am I missing here? Any suggestions or ideas on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You did not list your settings for the **Outbound rules** of the security group(s) attached to the instance. You should keep the "Allow All" outbound rules to allow the instance to access the Internet.

In general, **you should not modify the ACL rules away from their default "Allow All" setting** unless you have a very specific need (eg creating a DMZ). I recommend that you start by removing all custom rules from the ACLs and set the 'All traffic' option to "Allow". At least try this temporarily to try and identify the problem.

For example, when establishing a connection to the Internet, traffic will come from a randomly-assigned port. Your ACL is currently blocking all such ports. (To clarify: You might be connecting to port 80 on a remote computer, but that request is *not* coming from port 80 on your own computer. It is coming from a randomly-assigned port.)